# Get list of attribute values from list of beans

Tags: java, closures, javabeans

I have a list of beans and want to obtain a list of values (given a specific attribute).

For instance, I have a list of document definitions and I want to get a list of codes:

```
List<DDocumentDef> childDefs = MDocumentDef.getChildDefinitions(document.getDocumentDef());
Collection<String> childCodes = new HashSet<String>();
for (DDocumentDef child : childDefs) {
    childCodes.add(child.getCode());
}
```

Is there any more compact solution? Reflection, anonymous inner classes ...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's wrong with current approach?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just looking for a shorter/compact solution

Comment: I think there's not, but you can try to write an universal method which reads the bean fields using reflection by yourself. This isn't very difficult, but can have performance problems.

Answer (score 4):

I feel fine with your current approach.

But if you want to add a library (e.g. apache commons-collection and commons-beanutils) or you already have added it, you can do it this way:

```
// create the transformer
BeanToPropertyValueTransformer transformer = new BeanToPropertyValueTransformer("code" );

// transform the Collection
Collection childCodes = CollectionUtils.collect( childDefs , transformer );
```

the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) lib from google provides a similar api.

Answer (score 3):

There is no other way to do this with standard Java API. However, if you are comfortable, you can use [Guava's `Lists.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method:

```
Function<DDocumentDef, String> docToCodes = 
               new Function<DDocumentDef, String>() { 
                     public String apply(DDocumentDef docDef) { 
                         return docDef.getCode();
                     }
               };

List<String> codes = Lists.transform(childDefs, docToCodes);
```

Or, wait until Java 8 is out, and then you can use lambdas and streams for this:

```
List<DDocumentDef> childDefs = ...

List<String> childCodes = childDefs.stream()
                               .map(docDef -> docDef.getCode())
                               .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Now it's upto you to decide, which one do you prefer, and which one do you think is shorter.